# Problems with hot key memcached

Tags: php, memcached, shared-memory, apc

I have memcached keys that are as large as 2 MB and I can't reduce it, as the data has been already minified. It does go hot with many web servers accessing that key again and again. Is APC or shared memory a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Especially over slow network connections memcached could be significantly slower than local caches.
Local caches can be significantly faster because they avoid the network delay and protocol overhead.

APC and shared memory have often quite small size limits so make sure you configure it in a right way.

Another alternative for bigger items might be local files. If they are used quite often the operating system will keep them in memory and there won't be any disk access.